# how to display several bootstrap cards on the same row

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

i am trying to display retrieved data from database in cards using **bootstrap 4**  the data is retrieved correctly but the problem is in the displaying of these cards  because it just been displayed on a vertical way  each card on a row.

what i need is to display let say **3 or 4 cards on the same row**.

## code:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="card">
                <!--Card image-->
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

                <!--Card content-->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!--Title-->
                    <h4 class="card-title">name:{{ obj.name}}</h4>
                    <!--Text-->
                    <p class="card-text">{{obj.content}}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Come on! Move the container and the row outside of the loop, if you want to generate only one of each but loop through the objects for the columns!

Comment: this was the mistake thank you, i am new to bootstrap. i have another question if you can help me this will be greate.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with Bootstrap. If you put something within the loop, then you should expect N of them will be generated if there are N items in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{% for object in obj %} {% endfor %}` and place your content between. If you get some troubles with images try to store them in special folder and add .url in {{ obj.image.url }}.
settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Plus you can make images clickable (without this block images didn't show)

```
{% if project.url %}
<a href="{{ obj.url }}">
    <div class="ratio ratio-4x3">
        <img src="{{ obj.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2">
    </div>
</a>
{% else %}
<div class="ratio ratio-4x3">
    <img src="{{ obj.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2">
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the container and row outside the for loop
you can use this to display four items in single row

> `<div class="col col-sm-3 my-2">`